# SPUtility Error page isn't displaying

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow, workflow-activity

I tried to made a workflow in Visual Studio 2010 to Sharepoint 2010 and I need to send an error message to user.
My code:

```
private void codeActivity1_ExecuteCode(object sender, EventArgs e){
    var item = workflowsProperties.Item;
    foreach(String att in item.Attachments){
        if (att.EndWith(...)){
            SPUtility.TransferToErrorPage("This extension is not permited!");
        }
        else{
        ...
        }
    }
```

I have the workflow status "completed".
But the redirect to the Error page doesn't happen.
But when the item is already created and the workflow is activated manually, it works.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When the item is created, an event reciever starts the workflow, not the user. But if the workflow is started manually, it is done in user context.

You should stop the workflow with some message and not to redirect user to the error page.

Comment: I want to show a message but I don't know how

Comment: What kind of activity are you trying to create? Can you please update your question and add some code around the method (what inherits your class)?

Comment: is a normal workflow is her only method. I just want to send a message to the user

Comment: I need to show a message, in whatever place

Comment: Lukáš Nešpor you said "You should stop the workflow with some message and not to redirect user to the error page."... Now, how i do it. please